# Query that doesn't order results

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, limit

```
SELECT stuff FROM table LIMIT 0, 50
```

I'm repeating this query, while increasing the offset with 50 until I get no more results.

Will the order of the results be the same every time? I don't want to use ORDER BY because I don't need them ordered so it may decrease performance unnecessarily.

I just want to make sure that whatever the order is, it stays the same between queries so I don't get duplicate records in the other queries. From the tests I made it seems I don't...

Comment: If you use ORDER BY with a column that has an index on it (in particular, a primary key is always indexed), the performance hit is insignificant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, if you don't specify an ORDER BY, the order is not guaranteed. For what you want to do, you SHOULD specify an explicit ORDER BY.

*EDITED to reflect comments*

Anna, you are correct, if you perform this sequence of queries

```
SELECT stuff from table LIMIT 0, 50
SELECT stuff from table LIMIT 51, 50
SELECT stuff from table LIMIT 101, 50
... and so on ...
```

and you don't get a row in more than one result set, that is lucky.

If you repeat the query

```
SELECT stuff from table LIMIT 51, 50
```

a million times, there is a good chance that you'll get the same results each time but there's no guarantee.

Comment: so you're saying the fact that I didn't get duplicate results across queries is a coincidence?

Comment: Could you repeat a query a million times and get the same order of results without specifying an explicit order? Yes, but it can't be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

If your table as a primary key, then do:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table
ORDER BY pk
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Ordering by a primary key should be efficient.

In SQLite, you can also do:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table
ORDER BY rowid
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

`rowid` is a special "column" available for queries that is associated with the physical location of the row.  Ordering by `rowid` should also be efficient.